Как узнать почему не происходит обновления пакетов через dpkg в linux kali on wsl2?
Кто может помочь проблема в том, что при попытке обновления и апргрейда пакетов и зависимостей в Kali-linux внутри WSL2 подсистемы - не могу обнаружить, что именно загружает очередь выполнения процессов системы.
Пытался найти вначале, что именно загружается в очереди и использует сам пакетный менеджер dpkg, но с командой ps awux | grep dpkg
Всё, что нашел уничтожил как процесс через "sudo kill PID"
Сама система висит на этапе:

sudo apt upgrade

перед этим сделал sudo apt update, все прошло без ошибок.
Ps. хочу установить графическое окружение на kali.
Может можете помочь обычной инструкцией, какое проще установить?
Заранее благодарю.
Внизу появляется информация при использование ctrl+c в терминале вот:
# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-15) ...
^Cdpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libc-bin:
 libc-bin depends on libc6 (>> 2.37); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libc-bin depends on libc6 (<< 2.38); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
 libc-bin


1 способ. Создай файл /etc/wsl.conf и запиши в него
[boot] systemd=true

Если сразу не заработало, можно попробовать
$ wsl --update
$ wsl --shutdown

2 способ. Создать каталог /run/systemd/system.
P.s. Для кали на WSL есть kex, ставится очень просто. Тут подробно.
